# Dell BIOS update appears inefective

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, bios, battery

My Dell XPS M1330 currently has **BIOS version A11** which is too outdated to install windows 7 Home Premium.  I followed the  instructions on the Dell support site, downloaded the appropriate BIOS update executable (M1330A15.EXE) and ran it.

Since my battery has worn out it flagged an error saying that my computer didn't have a battery, but I can work around that by using `M1330A15.EXE /forceit` from a cmd prompt with elevated permissions.

It confirms that I want to update from A11 to A15 and I press OK. This causes Windows to shutdown. All good so far.

**The problem:**
After the shutdown there is a black screen for a few minutes after which windows starts normally. However when I check the BIOS version (with msinfo32.exe), it still shows A11!

It appears like the BIOS update was never flashed and that the black screen just timed out and started windows again :(. Any help or insight will be appreciated since there is no service center in my locality for the appropriate battery and vista is creating a lot of problems for me!

**Edit:**
The reason I need to update my BIOS is because Windows 7 CD gives the warning:

> The following issues are preventing Windows from upgrading...
>   Windows cannot be installed on this computer with the current system
>   BIOS version.
>
> Contact your computer manufacturer for a BIOS update,...
>   OEM Name: Dell Inc.; OEM Model: XPS M1330 ; BIOS Version: Phoenix ROM
>   BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A11;...

Also, it still shows A11 even in my BIOS setup screen!

Comment: What makes you think you cannot run Windows 7 with the A11 revision of your BIOS?  The only other method is to use a USB stick.  If Dell doesn't offer that method for their devices your really don't have another way to update your BIOS.

Comment: Does msinfo.exe just report that it has version 11, or does it actually have version 11. (Look at the BIOS screen when booting. Msinfo might just have old information).

Comment: What version of BIOS is reported during POST?

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited my question to include more appropriate information in response to your comment. Very sorry for the delay!

Comment: @Hennes see Edit (It is not just msinfo32.exe that is showing A11)

Comment: Interesting.  Dell must have unlocked a feature your hardware supports but didn't support the used BIOS.  Have you tried the DOS based flash method?

Comment: @Ramhound No.  am not aware of the procedure of booting into DOS. Besides, I don't have a floppy disk or a floppy disk reader or writer! I was really relying on their executable.

Comment: Well their executable does not work.  You can use flash drive normally in a situation like you describe instead of a floppy disk, but if you have to purchase a $20 USB floppy drive and return it that so bad?  Provide us a link the Dell product website I will investigate a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! But I'm afraid we do not have a return policy where I live instead I would like to consider the alternative of using a CD drive work around. Either way here is [my dell laptop link](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/xps-m1330). I can't wait to get rid of vista!

Comment: The problem is the executable will only work if your running the following operating systems ( Windows XP, Windows 2000, NT, Windows 9X, Windows ME ) which means you really have to do the MS DOS environment solution.

Comment: Ahh! Understood I will research and try it out when I am little  less preoccupied! I will report back here with the results. Thank you!